Pythonic approach to avoid nested loops for string concatination
I want to find all 5-digit strings, for which

the first three digits are in my first list,
the second trough fourth are in my second and
the third to fifth are in my last list:

l0=["123","567","451"]
l1=["234","239","881"]
l2=["348","551","399"]

should thus yield: ['12348', '12399'].
I have therefore written a funciton is_successor(a,b) that tests if a and b overlap:
def is_successor(a:str,b:str)->bool:
    """tests if strings a and b overlap"""
    return a[1:]==b[:2]

I can then achieve my goal by writing this nested loop/check structure, that basically appends back to front strings and resulting in all valid strings:
pres=[]
for c in l2:
    for b in l1:
        if is_successor(b,c):
            for a in l0:
                if is_successor(a,b):
                    pres.append(a[0]+b[0]+c)

pres


I know I could write it as a list comprehension, but for my original data i have more nested lists and i loose readability even in a list comprehension.
I start from l2 -> l0 because in my original data the lists become longer, the lower the index and thus I can filter out more cases early this way.
A single loop trough all combinations of l0,l1,l2 and checking the succession of all items a,b,c simultaneously would work but it test way more unnecessary combinations than my current construct does.

Question:
How can this nested loop and conditional checking call be astracted? Is there a pythonic way to capture the repetition of for -> is_successor()?
A larger input might be:

primes=[2,3,5,7,11,13,17]

lsts=[
    [
        str(j).zfill(3) 
        for j in range(12,988) 
        if not j%prime
    ] 
    for prime in primes
]


I think using map and filters functions may help. Link: https://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/map_filter.html

Can you share a realistic large input?

@nocomment see updated question

I would use itertools product to define a function that will perform the check annd append the data:
import itertools

def get_list(l1,l2):
    #THIS FUNCTION WILL TEST ALL THE PRODUCTS AND RETURN ONLY THE CORRECT ONES
    return [a+b[2:] for a,b in list(itertools.product(l1,l2)) if a[1:] == b[:2]]

then you can nest the function like this:
get_list(l0,get_list(l1,l2))

you will get the expected result: ['12348', '12399']
EDIT:
for a long list use reduce.
let s call l the list of list of inputs. In your specific case l = list([l0,l1,l2])
Reverse the list to apply from the end till the beginning l.reverse()
and the final code:
from functools import reduce 
reduce(lambda x,y:get_list(x,y),l)

Note: in this case you want to change the inputs of the "get_list" function as it will go l2 then l1 then l0.Just change the def of get_list like this: def get_list(l2,l1)

This does not help me with the problem of refactoring my deeper nestings. It further does not have the advantages of excluding unnecessary permutations if more lists are added.

it does eliminate the unnecessary checks with the list comprehension. And you can easily add a list comprehension in the function nesting for deeper needs. and you keep the readablility

You are right, I played with the code some more. But I still have to do the nested calls like get_list(l0, get_list(l1, ... get_list(ln, ln+1)...)) manually in the end.

you can use reduce. create a list of list and then apply reduce; just edited my answer

Thanks - the concept reduce() was actually what i was looking for

I changed: a[1:] == b[:2] to a[-2:] == b[:2] in get_list() and now it becomes one clean line of code: pres=reduce(lambda lnp1,ln:get_list(ln,lnp1),reversed(l)) where ln(p1) would be list of index n (+1)

You can rewrite it to work on arbitrary amount of lists in the following way:
First, put elements of the last list into sub lists with 1 element (this streamlines further processing)
ps = [[c] for c in l2]
print(ps) # [['348'], ['551'], ['399']]

Next, for each of the remaining lists check what elements match to elements in ps and add them to the beggining of matching elements.
for l in [l1, l0]:
    ps = [[a] + p for a in l for p in ps if is_successor(a, p[0])]

print(ps) # [['123', '234', '348'], ['123', '239', '399']]

Now assemble the final string back from lists
pres = []
for p in ps:
    pres.append(p[0]) # add entire element from l0
    for el in p[1:]:
        pres[-1] += el[-1] # add last character from following lists

print(pres) # ['12348', '12399']

As the only places we reference input lists directly is for l in [l1, l0]: and creation of initial list from a last one, this will work for any number of lists if those lines are updated.

If the lists contain more element, I'd suggest creating successor-dictionaries for all the elements in the list. Then you can directly combine those successors without iterating and testing all combinations.
from collections import defaultdict

l0=["123","567","451"]
l1=["234","239","881"]
l2=["348","551","399"]

def make_succ_dict(lst):
    d = defaultdict(list)
    for s in lst:
        d[s[:2]].append(s)
    return d

s1 = make_succ_dict(l1)
s2 = make_succ_dict(l2)

res = [a + b[2:] + c[2:] for a in l0 for b in s1[a[1:]] for c in s2[b[1:]]]
print(res)  # ['12348', '12399']

(This still uses nested loops, but it will not loop any invalid combination.)

A fast one working in two phases. First it goes backwards, building a graph connecting numbers with the matching numbers in the next list). And then reconstructing the valid paths/strings from the graph. Takes a few milliseconds to find the 1838 result strings of your larger example.
from collections import defaultdict

def pres(lsts):

    # Build graph of valid paths
    d = defaultdict(list)
    for s in lsts[-1]:
        d[s[:2]].append((s, None))
    for L in lsts[-2::-1]:
        e = defaultdict(list)
        for s in L:
            if s[1:] in d:
                e[s[:2]].append((s[0], d[s[1:]]))
        d = e

    # Reconstruct the paths
    pres = []
    path = []
    def reconstruct(nodes):
        if not nodes:
            pres.append(''.join(path[:]))
            return
        for s, nodes in nodes:
            path.append(s)
            reconstruct(nodes)
            path.pop()
    for nodes in d.values():
        reconstruct(nodes)
    return pres


# Test 1
l0=["123","567","451"]
l1=["234","239","881"]
l2=["348","551","399"]
print(pres([l0, l1, l2]))

# Test 2
from time import perf_counter as time
primes=[2,3,5,7,11,13,17]
lsts=[
    [
        str(j).zfill(3) 
        for j in range(12,988) 
        if not j%prime
    ] 
    for prime in primes
]
t0 = time()
p = pres(lsts)
print(len(p), p[:3], time() - t0)

Output (Attempt This Online!):
['12348', '12399']
1838 ['012056119', '012357289', '012658323'] 0.0051118419505655766


That is a really cool idea and indeed 10x faster on the large data sample! I did learn alot from your answer :) Thank you so much and have a great day!

Just a simple loop one:
l0=["123","567","451"]
l1=["234","239","881"]
l2=["348","551","399"]

pres = l2[:]
for L in l1, l0:
    pres = [s[0] + p
            for s in L
            for p in pres
            if s[1:] == p[:2]]

print(pres)

Attempt This Online!
